# IContextMenu3 HandleMenuMsg2 is never called

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, explorer, windows-shell

I'm trying to implement a shell extension that extends `IContextMenu3` and `IShellExtInit`, and i'm inserting menu items using the method described in section [HBMMENU_CALLBACK method](http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution) but in my project the method `HandleMenuMsg2` or the `HandleMenuMsg` is never called.

Can anyone please explain me what is required to receive the `HandleMenuMsg2` calls?

My ATL object is implemented like that:

```
    // CTestPlugin
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTestPlugin :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CTestPlugin, &CLSID_CTestPlugin>,
    public IShellExtInit,
    public IContextMenu3
{
public:
    CTestPlugin();
    ~CTestPlugin();

    HRESULT FinalConstruct();
    void FinalRelease();
public:
DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_TESTPLUGIN)
DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CTestPlugin)
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CTestPlugin)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IShellExtInit)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IContextMenu)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IContextMenu2)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IContextMenu3)
END_COM_MAP()
DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()
...
// IShellExtInit
    STDMETHODIMP Initialize(LPCITEMIDLIST, LPDATAOBJECT, HKEY);

    // IContextMenu
    STDMETHODIMP GetCommandString(UINT, UINT, UINT*, LPSTR, UINT)
    { return S_OK; }
    STDMETHODIMP InvokeCommand(LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO);
    STDMETHODIMP QueryContextMenu(HMENU, UINT, UINT, UINT, UINT);
    // IContextMenu2
    STDMETHODIMP HandleMenuMsg(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    // IContextMenu3
    STDMETHODIMP HandleMenuMsg2(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pResult);
```

And i'm inserting menu items like described in the nanoANT page:

```
bool CTestPlugin::AddNewMenuItem(HMENU hmenu, UINT un_menu_text_id, UINT un_menu_index, UINT icon, UINT& uCmdID)
{
    TCHAR chText[MAX_PATH];
    ::LoadString(
            _AtlModule.m_hResInstance, 
            un_menu_text_id, 
            chText, 
            MAX_PATH);

    MENUITEMINFO menuiteminfo;
    ZeroMemory(&menuiteminfo, sizeof(menuiteminfo));
    menuiteminfo.cbSize = sizeof(menuiteminfo);
    menuiteminfo.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_STRING;
    menuiteminfo.fType = MFT_STRING;
    menuiteminfo.dwTypeData = chText;
    menuiteminfo.cch = _tcslen(chText);
    if (icon) {
        menuiteminfo.hbmpItem = 
            SysInfo::Instance().IsVistaOrLater() 
            ? 
                _AtlModule.m_iconBitmapUtils.IconToBitmapPARGB32(_AtlModule.m_hResInstance, icon) 
                : 
                HBMMENU_CALLBACK;
    }
    menuiteminfo.wID        = (UINT)uCmdID++;
    m_mapIdToIcon[menuiteminfo.wID] = icon;
    return (TRUE==InsertMenuItem(hmenu, un_menu_index, TRUE, &menuiteminfo));
}
STDMETHODIMP CTestPlugin::HandleMenuMsg(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT res;
    return HandleMenuMsg2(uMsg, wParam, lParam, &res);
}

STDMETHODIMP CTestPlugin::HandleMenuMsg2(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT *pResult)
{
...
}
```

With all this the menu entries apear in explorer context menu but no images are displayed, both methods `HandleMenuMsg` and `HandleMenuMsg2` are never called, and the system that i'm testing is WinXP (in vista all is ok because we use the `hbmpItem`).

I'm missing some inicialization or what? can anyone explain me?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I happen to have been working on this today, and ran across your question. As I use pure WinAPI, I am not sure about the MFC semantics, but my best guess is that your `QueryInterface()` probably does not handle a request for the **IContextMenu3** interface.

(Although you probably solved this problem a long time ago. Still, others might find a use to knowing.)

Answer (score -1):

> menuiteminfo.fMask = MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_DATA | MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_STRING;

The fmask specifies what type of item you are inserting. On that line you say that the item is a bitmap string submenu.

Also, you specify MIIM_DATA but dont set `dwMenuData`.